# how to download all media files into my computer

Tags: media-library

How do I "download" all my photos from my media library to my local computer?

I can do this one at a time, but is there a way to grab them all at one time? Sort of like a "download all" process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best way of doing that would be downloading the wp-content/uploads directory, by ftp access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Bainternet.  This means there is no automated way of doing it from the Dashboard? I don't want my clients to have to ftp files.

Comment: if there is an automated way i never heard of it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

i found this plugin:

> #### [downML - Download Media Library](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/downml/).
>
> Helps admins to backup the media files available in the media library of the wordpress site.

it doesn't provide any options, just spits out a zip file for download. no ftp needed, works in the dashboard.

Comment: This plugin doesn't work well with large media libraries.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who is interested:

find yourself a php script that creates a zip from a list of files provided.

after that, use the script provided on this site: [Get All Images in Media Gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery), to create the list for the archiver script.

i hope this helps, at least this is the way i did it.

Comment: Will probably not work with large media libraries due to memory limits.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of ftp go to your cpanel and login. Open File Manager > Public HTML > wp_content > uploads....there will be folders with dates. Open them. You'll see your images. You can download them each or all at one time directly to your computer. Voila! I just did it myself. Hope that helps. By the way, ftp id faster. I use filezilla but it was having some inconvenient glitch at the moment so i did this 2nd option!

Comment: Where did the OP mention that he is using _cPanel_?