# Get All Images in Media Gallery?

Tags: media-library

Is there a way to fetch the URLs of **ALL** images in the media gallery?

I think this would be an easy way for a website to have a Pictures page that just pulls all of the images from the media gallery, granted it would only be necessary in certain scenarios.

I don't need instructions on how to create a Pictures page, just how to pull all of the image URLs. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean all images in the entire Media library (i.e., site-wide)?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```

All the images url are now in `$images`;

Comment: um.. looks like @somatic has beat me to it. Unlike his solution above, mine will only get images.

Comment: obviously our methods are similar... and azizur is right, adding the 'post_mime_type' to either query will narrow the types returned.

one thing to consider: the guid often does contain the full url to the image, but it is not a reliable source. It is static, generated only once when the post is created, and is built on the current site url and the media folder structure. But that folder structure *and* the domain could change at some point, and then the guid is not the actual image URL anymore, just a record of what it was when it was created...

Comment: This answer is **WRONG**. It does not get images from Media Library. It gets images used inside posts. Unused images are not found!

Comment: @Christian - is it wrong? Or should I ask 'still' wrong? I realise I'm commenting almost 2 years later, but I tried this out on WP 3.6 and I'm receiving images that I've just added to the media library without adding them to any posts :/

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but how would I now get the different image sizes?

Comment: @FrederikWitte you can combine [get_intermediate_image_sizes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_intermediate_image_sizes/) and [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) to get all the urls.

Comment: yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas

Comment: Some added context - this answer is **NOT WRONG**. WordPress stores upload data in the `wp_posts` table as a custom post type `attachment` every time you upload something regardless if it is used somewhere or not.

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of `post_status`? My code only works if I set `post_status` to `inherit`. However, the attachment I am looking for (a pdf file in my case) was not uploaded to any page. What is it inheriting from then? And why can't I just ignore the post_status?

Comment: Not working for me... I use this working code: 

How to show all WordPress Media Images on a page https://www.arnlweb.com/forums/web-development/how-to-get-all-images-in-a-wordpress-page-from-media-gallery/

Comment: @ApurbaPathak, I wold not recommend installing a plugins like the one suggested at the link you shared. This might lead to security venerability of your WordPress install.

Answer (score 18):

```
$media_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    )
);
$list = array();
foreach ($media_query->posts as $post) {
    $list[] = wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
}
// do something with $list here;
```

Query the db for all media library items (not just ones attached to posts), grab their url, dump them all in `$list` array.

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
    }
?>
```

This pulls all attachments for a post/page.
Attach more images to a post, and it will be listed

Answer (score 6):

ok y used this code for show ALL images in media Library!

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' =>25,
    'post_parent' => 210, // Post-> ID;
    'numberposts' => null,
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);

$post_count = count ($attachments);

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo "<div class=\"post photo col3\">";
        $url = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);// extraigo la _posturl del attachmnet      
        $img = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
        $title = get_the_title($attachment->post_parent);//extraigo titulo
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><img title="'.$title.'" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/timthumb.php?src='.$img.'&w=350&h=500&zc=3"></a>';
        echo "</div>";
    }   
}
```

and if you know method for show pagination, please answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a shorter version of this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11861/84219) using [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$image_ids = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
    ) );

$images = array_map( "wp_get_attachment_url", $image_ids );
```

Comment: This is the most optimized way. You are just calling the ID field which is the only one required.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though it hasn't been updated in a while, but the [Media Library Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-gallery/) plugin might be a good example to start looking at.