# add_submenu_page function to show videos table

Tags: menus, sub-menu, add-menu-page, wp-list-table

wondering if its possible to show the attachments admin list for videos by using a custom menu link?

Any pointers welcome! D.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages');
function mt_add_pages() {
    add_menu_page('Directors &amp; Showreels', 'Directors &amp; Showreels', 'manage_options', 'dsv_menu', 'wps_theme_func',null,2);
    $videos_page = add_submenu_page('dsv_menu', __('Videos','showreel_videos'),  __('Videos','showreel_videos'), 'edit_posts', 'sub-page-videos', 'display_showreel_videos');

}
function display_showreel_videos(){ ?>
     <div class="wrap"><h2>Videos</h2>
          <!-- get attachments by mime type ? (upload.php?post_mime_type=video ??)   -->
    </div><?
}
```

> got this working with class TT_Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table with help from links below... Looks fine but can't get edit or delete delete links to work properly.

```
$media_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', // get attachments only
        'post_status' => 'inherit', // attachments are not 'published', so set it to inherit
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // display all
        'post_mime_type' => 'video' // grab files with the mime type 'video'
    )
);

$list = array();

foreach ($media_query->posts as $post) {

    $list[] = array('thumbnail'=>'', 'ID'=>$post->ID,'title'=>$post->post_title);

}

//Create an instance of our package class...
$testListTable = new TT_Example_List_Table();
$testListTable->setContent($list);
$testListTable->prepare_items();
$testListTable->display();
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question and got this answer, to query the DB for attachments and dump them into a list. This was the code that was provided to me:

```
$media_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', // get attachments only
        'post_status' => 'inherit', // attachments are not 'published', so set it to inherit
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // display all
        'post_mime_type' => 'video' // grab files with the mime type 'video'
    )
);
$list = array();
foreach ($media_query->posts as $post) {
    $list[] = wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
}
// do something with $list here;
```

Hope this points you in the right direction. My question: [Get All Images in Media Gallery?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery)

---

**EDIT:** As far as displaying it in a table, I think you could truly benefit from digging through this code: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/

It has a working example of using `WP_List_Table` in WordPress. I took one glance and knew it would be a good code to check out. :)

Comment: thanks Jared. I think the main issue i have is rendering the table. Just found WP_List_Table class but no clear examples on how to pass results into it...

Comment: In that case you will want to read http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table and http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1//wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php -- I will try and prepare a working example for you.

Comment: @danielCrabbe I updated my answer with a link to some code you can benefit from.

Comment: thanks Jared. Mostly working now and just a few niggles to work out (i.e. delete links doesn't n not sure how to specify it).