# How do i create a search option for pdf's only

Tags: functions, jquery, search, pdf

I need help with a search page. We are a circuit court and use the latest version of WordPress for our website (flcourts18.org). We want the public to be able to search our administrative orders, which are all pdf's only from a specific folder where only the admin orders are stored. How do I setup a search page that will only search the pdf's from within a single folder? There are hundred of pdf's. We would like to search by AO# and by Text. Thank you for your help.

Comment: is it possible to extract the text you need to be searchable? I know if you have an elastic search instance then you can use a plugin to index your PDFs and it all becomes a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Any media item (including PDFs) is just another type of post. So you need to create a search that will look inside the media folder for all PDFs.

But that won't help search inside the PDF, though. That's a bit more complex, requiring the ability to 'look inside' the PDF file's content. And a bit complex to detail here.

But there are plugins that will do the work for you. One is [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/) , although it is a premium ($$) one. (Which might get me a downvote for recommending plugins, but I am of the opinion that pointing people in the right direction is a good thing.)  I have no experience with it, just noticed it via asking the googles.

There are other 'search enhancers' that you can find in the plugin directory, or by asking the googles.

You could also use the Google Search process to index (make searchable) your PDFs.

Comment: Can anyone help me (a non-coder tasked with coding) make my wp search list results for searched only in media gallery. Here is what i have so far:

Comment: if you go to http://flcourts18.org/?page_id=4762 you can see an example of what i trying to accomplish but can't get search box to search anything let alone specific pdf media

Comment: "Media" is just another post type of 'attachment'. See this answer to get started: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery . The first answer shows a wp_query that looks for media. So the query will return all media items. It will not 'search inside' the media (for instance, looking for a phrase inside a pdf). That's more complex. As for a page with just media on it, try my Multisite Media Display at https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-media-display/ . A shortcode in a page/post will display all media.

Comment: Your page will only search for titles of files (although hard to tell without seeing the query; I assume it's similar to the first link in previous comment). If you need to 'index' (make searchable) the content of pdf's, then Google Search is what I would do, although I do see some content searching plugins that have possibilities. You can customize GSE to your needs. There was a localized (search engine on your servers) searching program I installed 6 years ago, but can't recall the name - Sorry.